# forwarding subnet broadcasts in a small test environment

Tags: networking, router, routing, udp, broadcast

In my test lab I have a small, inexpensive, unnamed router to create two subnets, 12.1.1.0 and 172.17.2.0. The router is configured in Router mode (not Bridge), and I have a bridge defined that joins the two interfaces these subnets are on.

This is for testing software that relies on UDP communications between hosts on different subnets in large networks. Part of the requirements for these hosts is that they send 'route requests' to several broadcast addresses (one of which is the one the sending host lives on), so that the target host, regardless of subnet, will see the request and respond with a unicast reply. Thereafter the hosts communicate via unicast.

The configuration I'm using works fine as long as all hosts are configured with unicast targets, but a UDP broadcast for any foreign subnet dies on the receiving interface on the router.

In a real production environment, I can send a route request from (say) 12.1.1.15 to 172.17.2.255, and the network will relay the request packet intact to the correct subnet. Is there a general rule for routers that would cover this situation? Any technique will work as long as the host endpoints can successfully send broadcast traffic to other subnets. I don't have access to high-end routers.

Comment: Wait a moment; if they're supposed to be two separate subnets, with a router in between, _why_ is there a bridge defined that joins the two interfaces?

Comment: What you are doing is not supported and will not work with a lot of equipement. It may even give you erronous information back. For instance, on my system, the router replies success, but none of the hosts within the target subnet receive any packets. The correct way to do this is through multicast, not broadcast. And that needs support in the source, destination and router systems.

Comment: @user1686: the bridge is internal in the router, and that is how I got it to approximately work.

Comment: @Bib: I'm a developer trying to test a software application that runs in large, complex, production environments. I have a small lab for simulation and testing, and I need a 'black box' network environment that mimics what this application will see in real time.  The broadcast and multicast solutions are both in use by customers depending on their network implementation.

Comment: @buzzard51: Sure, but wherever it is, the interfaces being bridged contradicts them being two separate subnets.

Comment: @Bib: IPv4 has "directed broadcast" as a standard feature (pretty much as described in the main post), only IPv6 doesn't.

Comment: @user1686 directed broadcast is fine locally, but not across networks.

Comment: @Bib: It is fine across networks, because those networks don't know the difference. Until it reaches the destination subnet, it's unicast. That's the whole point of the feature.

Comment: @user1686 Check out smurf & fraggle attacks. It's been many years since I have come across any network which allows directed broadcast. Great way to start an DDoS attack.

Comment: @Bib: Hmm, good point, I see Linux no longer forwards them to the final subnet by default.

Comment: This is covered by RFC rfc1812 section-5.3.5.2 and rfc2644: directed broadcasts. Linux >= 4.19 has options to enable this: see https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.19#Networking (and note that it has to be enabled on the ingress (WAN) interface, not the (LAN) interface where the broadcast will finally happen). So if the router is running a recent (by "embedded standards", 4.19 is quite recent) Linux kernel and can be directly tinkered there might be an option.